# Adding a <br /> after a label only if label is visible. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a chunk of code that on page load with populates some of or all of the following labels. It should have two labels per line ( needs a line break after each xData label). The problem I am having is that since the number of labels with data and set to visable on page load changes, the `br /` tags cause spacing issues when not all labels are visible.

```
<div id="Status">
    <asp:Label ID="1" runat="server" Text="1:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="1Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="2" runat="server" Text="2:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="2Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="3" runat="server" Text="3:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="3Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
</div>
```

I would like to be able to add the line breaks after each "xData" label in the code behind when the labels are filled and set to visible.

I have tried adding `"\n"` to the label text and\or `Environment.NewLine` with no luck.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do they all need to be separate labels? Why can't you concat the string in a `StringBuilder` and output the HTML through an `<asp:Literal` ?

Comment: I guess they don't have to be, I was just trying to not change it too much as I am just stepping in to this code and didn't want to make major changes yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way...

```
<div id="Status">
    <div id="Status1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="1" runat="server" Text="1:" Width="125px" />
        <asp:Label ID="1Data" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
    <div id="Status2" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="2" runat="server" Text="2:" Width="125px" />
        <asp:Label ID="2Data" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
    <div id="Status3" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="3" runat="server" Text="2:" Width="125px" />
        <asp:Label ID="3Data" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The right way...

```
<div id="Status">
    <asp:Label CssClass="statusLabel" ID="1" runat="server" Text="1:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="1Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label CssClass="statusLabel" ID="2" runat="server" Text="2:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="2Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label CssClass="statusLabel" ID="3" runat="server" Text="3:" Width="125px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="3Data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
</div>

/* CSS */
#Status span {
  display: block;
}
#Status .statusLabel {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! @Brianary made the comment about being in the presentational layer and that got me thinking about not going with the literal. This got me headed to where I wanted to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it a couple of different ways.

One option would be what @Greg points out in his comment to your post.

Another possible option would be enclosing each label in its own `<div>` tag with `runat="server"` and then make these `<div>`s visible when needed. The `<div>` should create its own line break because of the nature of a `<div>`

Comment: In asp.net, the server-side div is a Panel control.

Answer (score 1):

asp:Label resolves to a span in html. If you want each one to have its own line, add the css style "display:block".  Usually, you can do this by setting CssClass and put display:block in that class

Comment: He needs two labels per line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this way, you need to use Literal control for each BR tag so that you can set it to visible/invisible based on the visibility of corresponding Label control.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get my head out of the sand. I was stuck thinking of how to do this is the control I had, and didn't even think about using another. If it wasn't for @brianary pointing out that this is the presentational layer, I would have used this (it did work great)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a CSS class with a `display: block` rule to those labels?

This is presentational, after all.

Comment: This is not good enough because he wants two labels per line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @brianary, made me rethink how I was approaching this and go with something like @Josh Stodola came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the labels around a `<div>` instead of putting a `<br />` at the end. In my experience, empty `<div>`'s don't create that empty space.